# preseed-file with apt-proxy/approx

Tags: preseed

i'm using approx as a apt proxy in our network. It's still working. Now I try to install 12.04 using a preseed file. This ist the section for the mirror:

```
d-i     mirror/country  string  manual
d-i     mirror/protocol string  http
d-i     mirror/http/countries   string  manual
d-i     mirror/http/proxy       string 
d-i     mirror/http/hostname    string tjener:9999
d-i     mirror/http/directory   string /ubuntu
d-i     mirror/suite            string precise
d-i     mirror/udeb/suite       string precise
d-i     mirror/udeb/components  multiselect main, restricted
```

Where tjener is the server.
But it's not working. During installation *http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu* is used. After installation in the source.list *http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu* is used. If i change *gb.archive.ubuntu.com* to tjener:9999 approx is used, so it's working.

The preseed settings work for 10.04 but not for 12.04. Can anybody help me.

Thank, you

Comment: You may need to add a static IP to name mapping in /etc/hosts using the preseed/early_command as depending on your network setup it may not be able to resolve that hostname. you should also remove/comment any lines if you aren't using them.

Comment: my god, i deleted the ' string ' token between the key and value and have been wondering why this never worked -_-

Answer (score 3):

Should you not add the proxy URL after `d-i     mirror/http/proxy       string`, that is if the proxy is need to access the internal mirror

FYI the exact config I use is as follows, the installation clients have no internet access but can reach the mirror:

```
d-i mirror/country string manual
d-i mirror/http/hostname string mymirror.org
d-i mirror/http/directory string /rep
d-i mirror/http/proxy string
d-i mirror/http/mirror select mymirror.org
```

Change `mymirror.org` and /rep for your site...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using *apt-cacher* as proxy, just **don't** set *mirror/http/hostname* to your proxy address, because apt-cacher retreive this address to get the URL of the downloaded file.

Here is a working configuration with Ubuntu 18.04. You can uncomment the first lines or use automatically guest configuration:

```
#d-i mirror/country string manual
#d-i mirror/http/hostname string archive.ubuntu.com
#d-i mirror/http/directory string /ubuntu
d-i mirror/http/proxy string http://192.168.0.1:3142
```